# WebForms and Azure Pipelines Package not being added to artifact

Tags: azure-devops, webforms, azure-pipelines

I'm having an issue with getting the package from msbuild to show up in the `build.artifactStagingDirectory`. My `.yml` file is really basic. Pretty much default.

I had to add some properties to the `NuGetCommand@2` task because it wasn't finding the packages to install.

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get the package file. I'm curious if it's related to the build task. I see warnings that it cannot find the packages from the NuGet Restore but I didn't think that it wouldn't build the zip file and whatnot. When running `msbuild` locally with all of the same switches it creates the package files as expected.

Here are the important bits of the yml file.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: 'src/WebFormsProj/packages.config'
    restoreDirectory: 'src/packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

I get the following warnings (one for each package):

```
Warning MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\a\1\s\src\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.4.1.60919\lib\40\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" because it was not found.


Could not copy the file "D:\Downloads\aspnetspell\ASPNetSpell\ASPNetSpell.dll" because it was not found.
```

I have other web apps that build and create the packages flawlessly. The difference is that this is a webforms project and not a web app. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Update:**

My project is located in a `src` directory. I noticed that the packages were being installed in the `src/WebFormsProj/src/packages/` directory instead of `src/packages`. I've since changed the `restoreDirectory` to `'$(Pipeline.Workspace)/src/packages'` directory. I'm still getting the "not found" errors though.

**Update 2:**
I found that *again* the packages weren't installing in the directory that it was trying to pull from. So I changed it yet again. This time with some success. I've changed restore directory once again to: `$(build.sourceDirectory)\src\packages'`

I also had to update a DLL that was pointing to a download directory rather than something local to the project in source control.

I'm still not seeing the publish package being created but I'm a bit closer now.

**Update 3**

I am finally able to get the files as an artifact. I had to add `/p:OutDir="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"` to the `msBuildArgs` and then update my publish artifact task with: `PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)_PublishedWebsites`

The next step is getting the transformations to apply. I still don't understand why I'm not getting the typical zip file that I do from web applications.

Comment: I have a testing web form project, the pipeline worked fine with the default configuration. Anyway, i am glad you finally worked it out. You can post your solution as answer.

Comment: If the vsbuild task cannot generate a zip file. You can use  [archive files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to create a zip file of the artifacts

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try setting the `restoreNugetPackages` attribute of VSbuild task to `true`. For below example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    restoreNugetPackages: true
```

Comment: restoreNugetPackages is deprecated. Nonetheless, I tried it and have the same results. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I've added a couple of the errors to the post. Essentially it warns me that it can't find the packages that it just installed. The NugGetCommand task does install them successfully.